# Using Millis instead of delay to reboot relay

Tags: arduino-mega, relay, millis, delay

I want to reboot relay (turn off , waiting 4 seconds and turn ON)
it works perfectly if I use delay(4000), but code is blocked while delay (4 seconds) and I cant start relay 2.
How can I use Millis instead of delay to reboot relay 1 and start relay 2 same time?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <EthernetUdp.h> //Load the Udp Library

//Ethernet
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED}; //Assign mac address
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 178); //Assign the IP Adress
unsigned int localPort = 80; // Assign a port to talk over
char packetBuffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE]; //dimensian a char array to hold our data packet
String datReq; //String for our data
int packetSize; //Size of the packet
EthernetUDP Udp; // Create a UDP Object                            //server port
String readString;

bool relayState = false;
//define relay pins
int relay_1 = 22;
int relay_2 = 24;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  Udp.begin(localPort); //Initialize Udp
  delay(2000);

  //Initial state of the relay
  pinMode(relay_1, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(relay_1, LOW); //relay 1 is On
  pinMode(relay_2, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(relay_2, HIGH);//relay 2 is Off


}

void loop() {

  packetSize = Udp.parsePacket(); //Reads the packet size
  if (packetSize > 0) { //if packetSize is >0, that means someone has sent a request
    Udp.read(packetBuffer, UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE); //Read the data request
    String datReq(packetBuffer); //Convert char array packetBuffer into a string called datReq
    //Serial.println(datReq);

    if (datReq == "relay1reboot") { //reboot relay
      digitalWrite(relay_1, HIGH);//relay off
      delay(4000); 
      digitalWrite(relay_1, LOW);//relay on

      Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort()); //Initialize packet send
      Udp.print("relay 1 reboot");
      Udp.endPacket(); //End the packet

    }
    if (datReq == "relay2on") {
      digitalWrite(relay_2, LOW);//relay 2 on
      Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort()); //Initialize packet send
      Udp.print("relay 2 on");
      Udp.endPacket(); //End the packet
    }
    if (datReq == "relay1on") {
      digitalWrite(relay_1, LOW);//relay 2 on
      Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort()); //Initialize packet send
      Udp.print("relay 1 on");
      Udp.endPacket(); //End the packet
    }
    // Use the snapshot to set track time until next event
    //previousMillis = currentMillis;
  }
}

//}
memset(packetBuffer, 0, UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE); //clear out the packetBuffer array

}
```

Comment: `reboot` is a term that is specific to programmable devices, such as computers ... it does not apply to a simple relay ... it would make sense to say `I want to cycle a relay`

Answer (score 2):

A general approach to remove a `delay()` is to replace it by some code
that:

- takes note that some action (whatever follows the `delay()`) will have
  to be performed in the future
- takes note of the current time.

Then, somewhere else in `loop()`, you check whether that “some action”
has to be done right now and, if this is the case, does it.

In this particular case, I would add a global boolean variable named
`relay1isRebooting`. When it is true, that means that the relay has been
turned off and will have to be turned on in the near future.

```cpp
bool relay1isRebooting = false;
unsigned long relay1rebootStarted;

void loop() {
  packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize > 0) { //we have received a packet
    // ...
    if (datReq == "relay1reboot") {
      digitalWrite(relay_1, HIGH); //relay off
      relay1isRebooting = true;
      relay1rebootStarted = millis();
    }
    // ...
  }

  // Switch back the relay 1 on if needed.
  if (relay1isRebooting && millis() - relay1rebootStarted >= 4000) {
      digitalWrite(relay_1, LOW); //relay on
      relay1isRebooting = false;
      Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
      Udp.print("relay 1 reboot");
      Udp.endPacket();
  }
}
```

Please note that the test for whether the relay 1 should be turned back
on is performed outside the `if (packetSize > 0)` block. Also note that
`relay1rebootStarted` has a valid value only when `relay1isRebooting` is
`true`.

Comment: for advanced coders: I usually use only the variable for millis. if it is 0 the timer is not running. `if (relay1rebootStarted && millis() - relay1rebootStarted >= RELAY_DELAY)`

Comment: @Juraj: I dislike this approach. Zero is a legitimate return value for `millis()`, returned every 49.7 days.